# Jquery focus out event and then submits the form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, confirm, focusout

I have a form textbox having focusout event on it. when the textbox loses focus, a confirm box pops, ask for "Ok" or "Cancel".

If user click Ok, form submits. How to do to accomplish this?

I tried this, but no luck:

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('#item_new').focusout(function() {
confirm("add this item?");

        'Confirm submit': function() {
            currentForm.submit();
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }

});
});
//]]>
```

please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you decompose your code, you'll see that the confirm and rest are not linked at all.

Here is some code that can help:

```
$('#item_new').focusout(function(e){

    // ask the user and keep his/her choice
    var ok = window.confirm('add this item?');

    // here, the 'ok' variable will be 'true' if OK was clicked,
    // false otherwise
    if( ok ) {
       // do the submit action.
       // replace '<id_of_the_form_to_submit>' with the id of the form
       $('#<id_of_the_form_to_submit>').submit();
    }
});
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arnaudj/c6z44mr9/

Edit:
note that the `window.confirm` call will make a basic browser-specific confirmation popup pop and that you cannot "decorate" as you want with style.

Comment: nvm, i got it! ^_^

btw, how to do if I like to add name and value to the Submit action?

for example, in html, we do:
<input type=submit name="dothis" value="yes">

thx again.

Comment: In jQuery, if you want to set an `attribute` of an element (here, it's your input of type submit), you do it with the `.attr()` method.
For setting values to DOM input elements, use the `.val()` method.

`$('#mySubmitId').attr( 'name', 'theNameOfTheButton');`
`$('#mySubmitId').val( 'The Value Of The Element');`

These informations are in the [documentation of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Hi Arnaud, can you test the code with Chrome? I tried again today, the window confirm pops twice. But works well with Firefox.

Comment: That's not the same message ^^.
The first one is a confirm when you focusout (go out of the input).

The second one was just to tell that the form has been submitted.